# useCallback hook and functions equality check problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, memoization

Trying to understand the `useCallback()` hook in react. In a blog post someone said that it solves the following problem:

> Before diving into useCallback() use, let's distinguish the problem useCallback() solves — the functions equality check.
>
> Functions in JavaScript are first-class citizens, meaning that a function is a regular object. The function object can be returned by other functions, be compared, etc.: anything you can do with an object.
>
> Let's write a function factory() that returns functions that sum
> numbers:

```js
function factory() {
  return (a, b) => a + b;
}

const sumFunc1 = factory();
const sumFunc2 = factory();

console.log(sumFunc1(1, 2)); // => 3
console.log(sumFunc2(1, 2)); // => 3

console.log(sumFunc1 === sumFunc2); // => false
console.log(sumFunc1 === sumFunc1); // => true
```

> `sumFunc1` and `sumFunc2` are functions that sum two numbers. They've been created by the
> `factory()` function.
>
> The functions `sumFunc1` and `sumFunc2` share the same code source, but they are different >function objects. Comparing them `sumFunc1 === sumFunc2` evaluates to false.
>
> That's just how JavaScript objects work. An object (including a function object) equals >only to itself.

So my questions:

1. How `sumFunc1 === sumFunc2` returns false
2. How the useCallback() hook solves that
3. How `useCallback()` hook is actually used for memoization?

Comment: "How sumFunc1 === sumFunc2 returns false" - They're not the same function. It's the same as [`{} === {}` being false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other).

Answer (score 2):

I think the latest version of the [React documentation on the `useCallback` hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) answers all three of your questions.

1. How `sumFunc1 === sumFunc2` returns false?

"In JavaScript, a `function () {}` or `() => {}` always creates a different function, similar to how the `{}` object literal always creates a new object" - from the docs. Expanding a bit more on that, in JS, functions are objects and they refer to specific blocks in memory. So when you create a new function, you essentially create a new object that points to a new block of memory. [This answer by Karol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31063445/8920806) expands even further on this with the actual specification.

2. How the `useCallback()` hook solves that?

Instead of recreating the function on re-render, the hook caches your function until its dependencies change. They have a great, [interactive example](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#examples-rerendering) in the docs.

3. How `useCallback()` hook is actually used for memoization?

It's used as wrapper for a function that you want to preserve, or more precisely, one that you don't want to change unless its dependencies (e.g. parameters) change to reduce the number of re-rendering.
For this one, make sure to check out [the interactive example](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#examples-rerendering) in the docs.

**⚠️ Please note**, don't use memoization for every function. [This is a great article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) on the topic that explains the pros and cons, the whens and wheres.